# How to gain access to LinkedIn Live Video API?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

The LinkedIn Live Video API [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/live-video-api) appears to be under the Marketing Developer Platform (MDP), however the MDP API [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/getting-started#what-permissions-are-available) regarding available permissions does not mention the `r_member_live` and `w_member_live` scopes required for the Live Video API. Are the `r_member_live` and `w_member_live` scopes included in the MDP API, or is there a separate application process for the Live Video API?

Answer (score 0):

You should find more information on accessing API through this link : https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

Also appreciate if you can please send in your query to our developer support from here https://developer.linkedin.com/support
You can also contact our Development Team at developeraccess@linkedin.com